# BlueJ controlling memory inside of software or method

Tags: java, javafx, libgdx, out-of-memory, bluej

For my final project I made a game using mostly `LibGDX`, `JavaFX` and some networking imports, I dealt with deleting everything once it was used to save as much memory as possible and it runs completely smooth on my home laptop. However the computer in school in which I have to present on crashes at the boss with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Now I know you can do stuff like `java –Xmx128m YourClassNameHere` when running from `cmd`, but I don't have access to `cmd` and I cannot manually change the java settings of the computer as they all require admin access.

Is there anyway to run `–Xmx128m` from inside my method, or in some parameter in `BlueJ` ?. I've searched through the preferences and settings of `BlueJ` but couldn't find anything of use.

Comment: If you can launch your game you should have access to the startup options

Comment: @efekctive I launch the game by clicking the void main(String[] args) directly in the blueJ application, where are the startup options?

Comment: Inside bluej. Read the bluej docs